# Terminal velocity of ball rolling down stair?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I am having a problem with a particular concept. 
  Here is where I have gotten, since the ball never loses contact with the stair, it will rotate around through the edges, the edges being the pivot, (used parallel axis theorem and all that), and since all collisions are inelastic,i figured the ball will lose the normal component of its velocity.But I still couldn't figure out how to find the terminal velocity(average). How and why?

I have posted an image for clarity.

[image]

Comment: You mention "all collisions are inelastic"; are you given the amount of elasticity in the problem, or are you just speaking from your own thoughts on that one?

Comment: The ball is supposed to be a solid

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I cannot locate the original yet.

Comment: Isn't the average of the motion the same problem as a ball rolling down an inclined plane?

Comment: A ball rolling down an incline won't have a terminal velocity,

Comment: An answer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I was able to find a solution, but it is super complicated.

I can offer though that the change in velocity when it hits the next step is

$$ \Delta v = \frac{m r^2 (\cos\varphi-1)}{I+m r^2} v_1$$

where $v_1$ is the impact (drop final) speed, $I$ is the mass moment of inertia, $r$ is the sphere radius and $\varphi$ is the sweep angle going from step to step. The sweep angle if $\varphi = 2 \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{h}{\sqrt{2} r} \right)$.

This comes from the contact condition at point *B* on the next step.

Those act to change the linear and angular velocity of the center of mass *C* in such a way as the linear velocities at point *B* is zero. Two equations and two unknowns.

$$(\vec{v}_C + \Delta \vec{v}) + (\vec{\omega} + \Delta \vec{\omega} ) \times ( \vec{r}_B-\vec{r}_C) = (0,0,0)$$

$$(\vec{v}_C + \frac{\vec{J}_A}{m} ) + (\vec{\omega} + \frac{(\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_C) \times \vec{J}_A}{I} ) \times ( \vec{r}_B-\vec{r}_C) = (0,0,0)$$

solving for the impulse $\vec{J}_A =(A_x,A_y,0)$ and used $\Delta v = | \vec{v}_C + \frac{\vec{J}_A}{m} | - |\vec{v}_C|$

The kinematics are driven by the locations
$$
\vec{r}_A = (0,0,0) \\
\vec{r}_C = (r \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right), r \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right),0) \\
\vec{r}_B = (r \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right) - r \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\varphi-\theta\right), r \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right)-r \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\varphi-\theta\right),0)$$

where the motion is described by the orientation angle $\theta = -\frac{\varphi}{2} \ldots \frac{\varphi}{2}$ which is the deviation from 45° of the line connecting the contact point A_ and the center *C*. Gravity acts to make $\theta$ positive. The angular velocity of the ball is $\vec{\omega} = (0,0,-\dot\theta)$.

If the initial speed is $v_0$ at orientation $\theta = - \frac{\varphi}{2}$ and final speed is $v_1$ at $\theta = \frac{\varphi}{2}$ then the fall is described by

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left( v_1^2 - v_0^2 \right) = \sqrt{2} r g \sin \left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right) $$

when $v_0 = v_1 + \Delta v$ we have reached the terminal speed. To find the average, you need the time $t$ it takes to sweep the arc and the distance the center travels $s = r \varphi$ for an average speed of $v_{ave} = \frac{r \varphi}{t}$.

Good luck.

Comment: cool, thank you very much, how did u get the first equation though. Can you send me a link or something like that.

Comment: No problem how complicated

Comment: I got from the 4 impulse + 4 constraints problem. Remember each impulse affects the linear velocity of the center of mass and the rotational velocity of the ball. I may add more details if needed, but the equations become rather long.

Comment: You are right. Something is awry. The general procedure is correct, but I am getting a negative impulse which is impossible. So I need to only consider impulse from _B_ and disregard the first contact condition.

Comment: Ughh.. I had edited the question with more details and I lost it (navigated away for a sec). Anyway use $$\Delta v = \frac{m r^2 (\cos\varphi-1)}{I+m r^2} v_1$$

Comment: How should i come up with this equation,

Comment: See edited post now.

Comment: i don't think it is correct,could u check ur solution one last time.

Comment: hey, what about the last equation, i guess you derived it from the conservation of energy, but i am getting a different equation.

Comment: Yes it is KE+PE throught the sweep angle. $$ \frac{v_0^2}{2} + g r \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} -\frac{\varphi}{2} \right) = \frac{v_1^2}{2} + g r \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{\varphi}{2} \right)$$

Comment: What about the moment of intertia, isn't it rotating around the edge of the stair

Comment: Oh .. yes, you are correct. The above captures the energy of the center of mass so you need to add a $\frac{1}{2} I \left(\frac{v}{r}\right)^2$ component on each side. (Do not use the mmoi about the pivot point, but rather about the center of mass).